# sql query to select sum state wise

Tags: php, mysql

```
id  | partyname | state     | constituency  | candidatename |    district  |    votes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
82  BJP         Maharashtra  Nagpur-East    Nitin Gadkari     Nagpur            1200

83  AAP         Maharashtra  Nagpur-East    Arvind Kejriwal   Nagpur            750

84  BJP         Maharashtra  Nagpur-West    Vicky             Nagpur            4800

86  AAP         Maharashtra  Nagpur-West    Lucky             Nagpur            3500

87  BJP         Maharashtra  Nagpur-North   Rakesh            Nagpur            100

88  AAP         Maharashtra  Nagpur-North   Ravan             Nagpur            1500

89  BJP         Maharashtra  Amravati-East  Amr               Amravati          320
```

**below is my query to get total sum of max value and partyname .**
**it works perfectly but it is only selecting nagpur consittuenciy**

**count not selecting count of amravati.**

above table shows my values in table like wise...
query display

aap = 1

bjp = 2

but this display bjp = 3
bcoz this bjp has also max value from amravati-east.

my meaning is query works perfect but this select all the data of maharashtra...
plz suggest me....

```
 <?php                
        $sqltoatl = "select t1.partyname as PARTY, count(*) as WinCount from voter_count t1, voter_count t2 where t1.votes > t2.votes and t1.constituency=t2.constituency
        group by t1.partyname";
        $resulttoatl = mysql_query($sqltoatl);
        WHILE($rowtoatl = mysql_fetch_array($resulttoatl,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>                
         <tr>  

          <td><?php echo $rowtoatl['PARTY']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $rowtoatl['WinCount']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: what you want actually I am not able to understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: my query is not selecting value of id=89 from above data, if it works properly then output will like aap = 1,bjp = 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [php code to get sum of counted value and display as sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282192/php-code-to-get-sum-of-counted-value-and-display-as-sum)

Comment: Please add the `column name` which you want eg.  `constituency ` in select statement

Comment: what do you want in output just clear it.....

create table structure same as main table so I can understand that easily

Comment: ok, if I understand your problem correctly, your query has a logical mistake in it: `.. from voter_count t1, voter_count t2 where t1.votes > t2.votes and t1.constituency=t2.constituency` the problem is, if there is only one constituency, i.e. Amravati-East in your case, it wouldn't be included in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure if you are looking for something like this.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS voter_count AS
      ( SELECT *
       FROM
         ( SELECT 82 AS id,
                        'BJP' partyname,
                        'Maharashtra' STATE,
                        'Nagpur-East' AS constituency ,
                        'Nitin Gadkari' candidatename,
                        'Nagpur' district,
                        1200 votes
          UNION SELECT 83,
                       'AAP',
                       'Maharashtra' ,
                       'Nagpur-East' ,
                       'Arvind Kejriwal',
                       'Nagpur',
                       750
          UNION SELECT 84,
                       'BJP',
                       'Maharashtra' ,
                       'Nagpur-West' ,
                       'Vicky',
                       'Nagpur',
                       4800
          UNION SELECT 86,
                       'AAP',
                       'Maharashtra' ,
                       'Nagpur-West' ,
                       'Lucky',
                       'Nagpur',
                       3500
          UNION SELECT 87,
                       'BJP',
                       'Maharashtra' ,
                       'Nagpur-North' ,
                       'Rakesh',
                       'Nagpur',
                       100
          UNION SELECT 88,
                       'AAP' ,
                       'Maharashtra' ,
                       'Nagpur-North' ,
                       'Ravan',
                       'Nagpur',
                       1500
          UNION SELECT 89,
                       'BJP',
                       'Maharashtra',
                       'Amravati-East' ,
                       'Amr',
                       'Amravati',
                       320) VoteTable );
```

This query will give you the full details, this will be useful when there is a tie.

```
    SELECT voter_count.*
    FROM
      (SELECT constituency,
              MAX(votes) Votes
       FROM voter_count
       GROUP BY constituency) results
    INNER JOIN voter_count ON voter_count.Votes = results.Votes
    AND voter_count.constituency = results.constituency;
```

May be this is the query you are looking for

```
    SELECT partyname,
           count(*)
    FROM
      (SELECT constituency,
              MAX(votes) Votes
       FROM voter_count
       GROUP BY constituency) results
    INNER JOIN voter_count ON voter_count.Votes = results.Votes
    AND voter_count.constituency = results.constituency
    GROUP BY partyname
```